# JWPlayer handle youtube errors

Tags: javascript, youtube, jwplayer

I would like to handle the youtube errors in the JWPlayer, so in case the video doesn't exists or is not available for the country show a message on the player, or with javascript, i am doing something like this...

```
var options = {                             
                    height: 330,
                    },
                    flashplayer: '/player.swf',
                    width: 560,
                    events:{
                        onError:function(obj){
                            alert('ERROR'+obj);
                        }
                    }            ,
                        debug: 'console'
                };


 jwplayer("player").setup(options);
 jwplayer("player").play();
```

but its not getting inside from the onError event, even though the video doesnt even exist... and i can see in the console.. LOG (Error loading preview image: Error #2036)

In the case of youtubes restriction country i cannot even see that in the console.

In any case the video just show the loading animation, which it makes belieave the user that it can be load in any time, which its not true.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/jwplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/swfobject.js"></script>
```

```
            <div id="player"></div>

            </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            //<![CDATA[  

            window.onload=createPlayer();

            function createPlayer() {
                var flashvars = {
                    file:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnEHsUWFuNM", 
                    autostart:"true"
                }
                var params = {
                    allowfullscreen:"true", 
                    allowscriptaccess:"always"
                }
                var attributes = {
                    id:"player1",  
                    name:"player1"
                }
                swfobject.embedSWF("#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/player.swf", "player", "320", "196", "9.0.115", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
            }   
            function loadPlayer() {
                var options = { 
                    height: 325,
                    flashplayer: '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/assets/player.swf',
                    width: 560,
                    events:{
                        onError:function(error){
                            alert('Error loading your link, please try another one');
                        }
                    }       /*     ,
                            debug: 'console'*/
                };
                options.file = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnEHsUWFuNM';                    
                options.events.onReady= function(){      

                    jwplayer("player").play();

                };

                jwplayer("player").setup(options);
            }
            //]]>
        </script>
```

loadPlayer to try with jwplayer.js and the createPlayer directly from SWFObject... that video exist just that it shouldnt be shown in germany, still its trying to load it.
and if i set any other unexisting URL let say "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABC" still keeps trying to load the unexisting video.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: I have one link, but doesnt work for external access yet...
Its there a posibility which it can be explained this behaviour without accesing?
Or that you know it had happpend in past ocasions?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue before, so I really want to debug why this would be happening.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of JW5, btw, 5.10. Also for JW5, the API Reference is here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31164/javascript-api-reference

Comment: Yeah, i had the version 5.8, just updated but still same issue,
I can get the error callback when using swfObject, but not when i use the setup of Jwplayer, which i need for plugins and some other things

Comment: Bu the other event works.. i have for example, onTime, and it works just in the case of onError that its not fired for some reason

Comment: I would try to embed with jwplayer.js, all of the events should work with it.

Comment: Sorry, what do u mean exactly with using jwplayer.js, im currently using jwplayer.min.js... should i use the jwplayer.js and if i should which js should i include?

Comment: That should be fine then, since you are using 5.10. I will need to see where this is running then at this point.

Comment: Well, i will keep making some attempts, still have no idea why its the only event without working, i will let u know if i figure out

Comment: Okay. If you can put up an example too, that would be helpful.

Comment: Well i thought that it was working using swf directly but not even that, i will post a small code, and still its not showing anything but just trying to load the video for ever, even though the video its unavailable in Germany, just keeps trying it to load, and i cannot show a proper message to the user.

Comment: Can I still see something at least?

Comment: Sorry, im trying to make the server work, but it is down.. anyways, i uploaded a simple example here.. you can check the files.. Thanks in advance
http://sdrv.ms/1aWXoef

Comment: Do you have any link were i can see the Error function executing?

Comment: We just have our reference pages. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, I looked at your page, and I tested locally with JW5 as well, but it didn't work, but it does work with JW6. I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like JW5 doesn't support catching YouTube errors. However, the following setup with JW6 works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YouTube Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
      file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCD",
      events:{
            onError: function() {
                jwplayer().load({file: "http://content.longtailvideo.com/videos/flvplayer.flv",duration: "27"});jwplayer().play()
                }
            }
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now i know then its not possible to do so, in version 5, i will try a work around, since i cannot change to version 6 yet, i will have to rework the plugins used for that

Comment: No problem, any time!

Comment: Yeah i noticed that the errorCode its being always 0! so its not setting any error message in the onPlayerError.
The solution its to create a default in the switch in case of any error. Even though we cannot differentiate them, at least we are aware than an error ocurred

Comment: Yeah, you could do that.